# Can Windows 8 build Windows 10 IoT Core Application?

Tags: windows, windows-10, iot, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

Am I able to build a Windows 10 IoT Core Application in Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 8 machine?

The following page made me think that I have to have a Windows 10 machine to build Windows 10 IoT Core apps. Didn't know if anyone has used Windows 8 or not...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/GetStarted/noobs/GetStartedStep1.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows 10 IoT core support two types of app. UWP app and non-UWP app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/buildingappsforiotcore).

> UWP are primary app type of Windows 10 IoT core. It is a common app
>   platform across all version of Windows 10, including Windows 10 IoT
>   Core.

Both of them need Windows 10.

So, the answer is no. Because some new features introduced in Windows 10 are not supported in Windows 8. For further clarifications, reference the following links:

[Windows 8 apps vs UWP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/54808b94-5f57-4299-ab00-a9f92709ccc9/uwpwindows-8-apps-vs-uwp?forum=wpdevelop).

[Universal Apps on Windows 8/8.1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3f9c0b76-8a7a-4c0c-a33b-33dce61b9e5b/uwpuniversal-apps-on-windows-881?forum=wpdevelop).